# Linear Gradient between two points

Tags: java, algorithm, processing, gradient

I'm trying to generate a linear gradient on my pixel raster. I do this in processing 2.0 - this is mainly Java but with some extra classes and variables. I already have a function to do a radial gradient:

```
/* For every pixel */
  distance = dist(centerX,centerY, x,y); //calculate distance between position and center of gradient
  lerpValue = norm(distance, 0, maxRadius) //normalize this value between 0 and the give maximum radius
  color = lerpColor(startColor, endColor, lerpValue ); //calculate Color
/*end for*/
```

This was easier than I thought. Then I tried to do a gradient from one point to another, and I can't figure out how to calculate this. Of course a horizontal or vertical gradient is no problem, but within two points the line could be any angle. 
I already found an answer to a similar question but actually I didn't understand it. Would someone explain to me how this calculation is possible - with description in easy words? Please explain what your're doing because I want to understand it and not just copy it. And if you write code please give the variables good names. I know it's faster to write single character names but I don't always know what exactly they are. 
Oh and the calculation should be pixel per pixel, because rotating lines and drawing them every x steps is pretty slow I think and can lead to ugly results (wrong colors with antialiasing, stairs without).
I hope I don't ask too much but as I said I really want to understand how this works, and that's pretty hard if i have to guess e.g. what the names of variables mean..

Comment: _" I already found an answer to a similar question but actually I didn't understand it."_ Please link the question. It may provide inspiration to potential answerers :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869785/point-to-point-linear-gradient?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very simple, and similar to what you do for the horizontal and vertical gradient.

The exact maths varies based on exactly how you want the gradient to appear - but basically you do the same as for the vertical and horizontal gradient but combining both X and Y into it.

You work out the distance vertically, and the distance horizontally. We will call them v and h.

You then combine them to give the total distance and use that as your lerpValue.

For example to have both width and height have the same contribution

```
lerpValue = 0.5*v + 0.5*h;
```

To make height have twice as much contribution as width:

```
lerpValue = 0.33*v + 0.67*h;
```

To make the gradient even even if you are filling a rectangle rather than a square:

```
double ratio = width/height;

lerpValue = ratio*v + (1-ratio)*h;
```

etc.

Comment: I'm sorry but the distance between what points? Actually I have three points:

x/y of the point where the gradient starts
x/y of the point where the gradient ends
x/y of the pixel I'm calculation at the moment (position in loop)

If I would calculate the distance between the first two points, I would get the same color on all pixels obviously, because they don't change.. If I would calculate with e.g. the first pixel, I wouldn't use the stop point. sorry if this question is silly...

Comment: I don't know if it was clear what exactly I want to do, so here you have a pic showing this (done in photoshop of course).

http://imageshack.com/a/img607/6615/vh4c.png

I have a startPoint and an endPoint with x/y, and try to calculate every single pixel to get a result just like the image shows. I hope this helps. thank you :)